# Commands to write text to a buffer

Tags: vimscript, command-line, buffers

I'm writing a plugin that often needs to write text to specific buffers. 
My current solution is to make the script execute normal commands that open a split with the buffer, write the text and then close it thus returning to the previous split.

Although this is fast enough for the intended purposes, it feels a bit dirty. Is there a more clean/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check vim help for the following entries:

- `:h function-list`
- `:h setbufline()` -- what you probably need
- `:h getbufline()` -- and also this.
- `:h appendbufline()` -- and this.